# Why does my bath faucet drip for a few minutes after it's shut off?

Tags: bathroom, leak, faucet, bathtub, taps

I have a traditional two handled (one hot and one cold and they are separate) bath faucet. I recently had it reseated and the washers replaced, however, what I noticed was that immediately after shut off, there is still water coming out of the faucet, but slowly after a 3-5 minutes there eventually will not be any water dripping out of the faucet. All my other faucets in the bathroom do not drip at all immediately after shut off. I can't figure out why. I really want to understand if this is normal or whether this is fixable. It's annoying to me now because every time I use the bath I tend to stare at the faucet until it stops dripping.

[This picture](http://www.renovationd.com.au/images/betis_bath.jpg) looks very similar to my bath faucet.

Comment: Does it matter whether it's just the hot or just the cold?

Comment: After you shut it off, Turn the diverter to shower and back.  Does the water flow out all at once and stop?

Comment: @waxeagle I've tried to turn on/off both the cold/hot tap individually I didn't know any difference in the amount of water dripping out of the spout. I also felt the temperature it was always cold.

Comment: The diverter is that little stick on the faucet.  Give it a tug and see if it drains faster.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore sorry I knew I didn't find the right picture last time so here you go. Again mine don't have the diverter. http://www.renovationd.com.au/images/betis_bath.jpg

Comment: So there's no shower?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore no.

Answer (score 2):

I have an American Standard Cadet 2-handle faucet which does precisely the same thing.  And don't feel lonely, I do the same as you too. lol I bet the final pesky dripping has to do with the associated residual layer of water on the inside of the pipes after the handles are turned off.  Just like an upended ketchup bottle which is empty enough to no longer squirt, but left inverted will eventually cease dripping once gravity has removed the layer of ketchup from the inside surfaces.  I realize this is opinion, however I've pondered the pesky drips while sitting in my tub many, many times over the years.  That's pretty personal experience...

Answer (score 2):

My faucet dripped for 30 minutes after I shut the water off and I finally figured out why.  It was driving me crazy.  I have a knob on top of the tub spout that when pulled up activates the diverter valve and sends the water to the shower head. The knob is screwed in to the diverter valve and was screwed in too tight causing the valve not to return to tub mode all the way. This allowed water from the shower head to slowly drip down for many many minutes. I simply turned it counter clockwise and that allowed it to go to tub mode when the water was shut off.  Now the water stops dripping after several seconds!  I hope this helps somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a plumber come in yesterday for something unrelated. My sink and bathroom faucets as well as my shower faucet occasionally do the same thing. What Jus said was exactly what the plumber said. As long as it doesnt do it for more than 20 minutes or so, It is completely normal